# Using VBA to perform a vlookup

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following vba code to perform a vlookup.  Strangely it only works when there is text in the lookup value (cell C1).  If the lookup value in cell C1 is a number (not text), it does not work.  Any thoughts on why?

```
    Sub FINDVAL()
    On Error GoTo MyErrorHandler:
    Dim E_name As String
    E_name = Range("C1").Value
    If Len(E_name) > 0 Then
      Sal = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(E_name, Sheet1.Range("A1:B100000"), 2, False)
      MsgBox "Salary is : $ " & Sal
    Else
      MsgBox ("You entered an invalid value")
    End If
    Exit Sub
MyErrorHandler:
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
      MsgBox "Employee Not Present in the table."
    End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Because you "dim" E_Name as a String, I'd think. So you're passing VLookup a String, meaning it will match only strings? From the documentation, concerning the fourth argument in the function: "If the range_lookup argument is FALSE, VLOOKUP will find only an exact match". Why not pass `Range("C1") instead of E_name?

Comment: Consider dimensioning E_Name as Variant type so it can receive either text or numbers.  Also make sure the formula you are working with in excel works the way you want it to in excel before placing it in VBA worksheetFunction.  You may also want to consider specifying which worksheet you are using to reference C1.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question for future references, if for some reason you need to declare a variable as a string ,but will also encounter integers. You can do something like this.

```
 If Len(E_name) > 0 Then
        If IsNumeric(E_name) Then
            Sal = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CDbl(E_name), Sheet1.Range("A1:B100000"), 2, False)
        Else
          Sal = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(E_name, Sheet1.Range("A1:B100000"), 2, False)             
        End If
      MsgBox "Salary is : $ " & Sal
 Else
      MsgBox ("You entered an invalid value")
 End If
```

Comment: I suggest you meant `CDbl(E_name)`... because looking for "1.5" may lead to errors with `CInt(E_name)`

Comment: @DirkReichel, good catch. I was not thinking there were decimal numbers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are declaring the variable `E_name` as `String`. Any variable initialization following such a declaration will only accept `String` values.

Only define the **datatype** of the variable if you are sure that all instances of it will be of the same datatype.

**In this case since you can have numeric as well as character values in `C1`, you should declare `E_name` of the datatype `Variant` which is a universal datatype.**

When in doubt, check the datatype of your variables using the `TypeName()` method.

Example:

```
Public Sub variantTest()
    Dim E_name As Variant

    E_name = "John"
    Debug.Print E_name & ":" & TypeName(E_name)     'Prints "John:String"

    E_name = 2
    Debug.Print E_name & ":" & TypeName(E_name)     'Prints "2:Integer"

    E_name = 9.99
    Debug.Print E_name & ":" & TypeName(E_name)     'Prints "9.99:Double"

    E_name = #1/1/2016#
    Debug.Print E_name & ":" & TypeName(E_name)     'Prints "01-01-2016:Date"
End Sub
```